# where did they get my Gmail address?

Tags: google

I pointed my browser at the website of a web developer I barely know, and the page returned was his home page, with the message "Welcome myname@gmail.com!"

Whoa. Where did it get my Gmail address? Never seen that before. I was logged in to that Google account at that time, but somehow that login account is accessible to someone whose web page I go to. That info sure isn't contained in any Apache logs, though certainly my IP address is. I am aware that Google makes all kinds of information available to users, unless one tells them not to.

1. How does one prevent one's Gmail address from being transmitted to a website, so as to preserve some semblance of anonymity?
2. How do you set up a website to get that info?

Comment: What website was it, and what browser were you using?

Comment: We might need to inspect the page's code to narrow down the possibilities, else we're guessing.

Comment: If you provide the URL, we can take a look.

Comment: You need to provide the URL, we cannot help you at all if you don't.

Comment: And if you provide your gmail-address, we can lookup your whole life. Have you heard about the Truman Show?

Comment: I am using Mac Firefox 40.0.

Um, wait. What that web page showing me is a Google Drive pane, which says "You are signed in as xxxx@gmail.com".

So does this mean that Google Drive is telling me who I am signed in as, but not telling the website owner who I am signed in as? I have no problem with that.

Comment: @user618: Exactly. Only Google domains can access that information and the website owner has no access to it.

Comment: Thank you! Kind of funny that if you aren't looking carefully it looks like the website knows who you are!

Comment: i *think* i know the answer, after searching the web for possible explanations. take a look at this [blogpost](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/detect-visitor-social-networks/). I can't explain it any further right now, but i hope i point you to the right direction! you can test it on this [demo-link](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/tools/detect-social-network-logins/).

Comment: @Gewure that only works for detecting if someone is logged in to, for example, Google, not for obtaining the e-mail address.

Comment: @Gewure - I tried the "Demo" page: http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/tools/detect-social-network-logins/ (Thanks for the links). It appears to be working for Facebook, Google, and Google+, but not for Twitter. Perhaps this is temporary, or perhaps Twitter has changed their site and the script no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

The website is simply asking the Google login handler to display the information to you -- and then placing it on the website in such a fashion that it appears to be the website knowing your logged in account. But in truth it's just a tag to them, like <%InsertLoggedInName%> or something like that.